# How to create a status bar icon on the right side? (Android)

Tags: android, icons, notifications, notificationmanager

`Notification` and `NotificationManager` are used to create icons to be placed on the top-left position of the screen. A `Notification` also need to have an entry on the status bar pull-down.

However, icons on the right side such as the battery, signal strength, wireless indicators do not need any entry on the status bar.

How do I make such icons without any entry in the status bar pull-down?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a Notification \ status bar icon on the right side?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350016/how-to-create-a-notification-status-bar-icon-on-the-right-side)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe the right side area of the notification bar is reserved for the OS.

Comment: Google Japanese Input displays A or あ icon on the right side. It is not a system application, and it did both on a 4.4.2 Samsung device and on a 5.1.1 Nexus device. So there must be some kind of API.

Comment: Note that I wrote this answer in 2010. If there is a way to do this in newer versions of Android, feel free to add that as a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you accept the above answer . . . if you take the android source and build it yourself then setting the icon on the right side isn't impossible. I've Started a new Question with this check here  [How to create a Notification \ status bar icon on the right side?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18350016/2614215)