# Notification drawer in google plus app

Tags: android

I want to implement Right side notification drawer in my android app like the google plus app. I tried doing it with navigation drawer but the action bar drawer toggle takes drawer layout as input instead of a particular view and thus reacts to both left and right drawer unlike g+ app.

Sliding drawer could be another option but that has been deprecated in API level 17. What can i use to implement that functionality in my app?

here is an image of what I want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkH30.png

Answer (score 1):

Use this library: http://www.androidviews.net/2013/04/sliding-layer/ I's quite simple to implement and saves you from doing this yourself.

Github page: https://github.com/6wunderkinder/android-sliding-layer-lib

Comment: I have seen this before. I downloaded the sample app but looks like it doesn't support the swipe gesture like g+ app. I want that gesture so that both left navigation drawer and right sliding drawer open with gestures. How do I implement that?

Comment: @gitter sorry about that, I was confusing that one, with this one: https://github.com/adamrocker/simple-side-drawer

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading the [official developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) first.

Also [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350016/how-to-create-a-notification-status-bar-icon-on-the-right-side)

TL;DR:

I have one easy idea:

In manifest declare android screen orientation as landscape and design like landscape for portrait mode so that your app looks portrait in landscape mode.

Comment: I am looking for in app notifications (like g+ and facebook), not the android notification drawer.