# How to create sliding layout like in Google Drive tablet app or Google+ notifications?

Tags: android, android-layout, slidingdrawer

I'd like to create an extra-information view similar to that of the Google Drive app (below)[image: Google Drive app] on a tablet. When the info button is clicked, this view slides in from the right[image: this view slides in from the right]containing a layout. Another example would be the Google+ app with its notifications slide-out panel:[image]. The [SlidingLayer by 6Wunderkinder](http://www.androidviews.net/2013/04/sliding-layer/) almost works, but doesn't fade a semi-black background over the views behind the "drawer" and I haven't found another library that does this.

If anybody has any suggestions/solutions please let me know!

Also, I've already looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19083363/notification-drawer-in-google-plus-app) and none of the answers suggested there are correct either.

Answer (score 3):

For posterity, here's the answer to this question. As Steve Benett's suggestion led me to discover, the correct way to do this is to use two `DrawerLayouts`, nested within each other like so:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_navigation_bar"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_sidebar"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_main_content"
            android:name="MainContentFragment"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_sidebar"
            android:name="SidebarFragment"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="end" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_bar"
        android:name="NavigationFragment"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The innermost `DrawerLayout` contains the main content of the `Activity`, whether it be a fragment or some other layout components. `fragment_sidebar` is the fragment that will be swiped out from the right. Then, on the top-level `DrawerLayout` you have the `fragment_nagivation_bar` which houses the left Drawer's `ListView` or whatever.

Then, in the Activity Java code you have:

```
mDrawerLayoutLeft= (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_navigation_bar);
mDrawerLayoutRight = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_sidebar);

mDrawerLayoutLeft.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
mDrawerLayoutRight.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.sidebar_shadow, GravityCompat.END);
```

An optional addition (but recommended, for consistency of UX) is to hide the other Drawer when one is opened, so your screen doesn't consist solely of Drawers.

I hope this has helped somebody!

Comment: Have you tried to fully implement the NavDrawer like suggested in the links I provided? Is it possible with your setup that only one drawer is synced with ActionBar up Button? I now another approach to have two NavDrawers at the same time. But it leads into very ugly code, if you try to sync one NavDrawer with the up Button.

Comment: Yes, only the `mDrawerLayoutLeft` is synced with the `ActionBar` hamburger home button. I didn't show it but I have an `ActionBarDrawerToggle` set up and then I call `mDrawerLayoutLeft.setDrawerListener()`. It works well.

Answer (score 2):

This is the [DrawerLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html). Have a look at [the design guide](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html), which illustrates the behavior well.

If you want to use / customize the "semi-black background" use DrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow() with a drawable. Google hands out a set of drawables [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html). Download the **ActionBar Icon Pack** and look for the **drawable_shadow.9.png**.

If you want that the menu appears from the right, set `android:layout_gravity="end"` as a property in the second child of the layout.

Comment: Okay, so now I have two DrawerLayouts nested, one containing the `layout_gravity="start"` View and the other containing the `layout_gravity="end"` View. The problem now is that, despite having two `DrawerLayout` objects in the Java code, and setting the drawer shadow to each, the one on the right does not black out the screen in the background.