# Is possible to add icon on statusbar on right side

Tags: android, notifications

I'm wondering if it's possible to add an icon on the right side of my statusbar (**PROGRAMMATICALLY WITHOUT ROOT**), I've read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350016/how-to-create-a-notification-status-bar-icon-on-the-right-side) but it didn't help me out.

I've read this [support.google.notifications](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6073642?hl=en) and on the side when explains `See notifications at the top of your screen` it says:

1. Left side

> These are your notifications. When you get a notification, you'll see its icon at the top-left of the screen. When you want to read a notification, pull down the notification shade from the top of the screen.

2. Right side

> These are your device's system icons. You'll see a star in the right of the the status bar when you've set your device to only show priority notifications. You'll also see system icons, including Wi-Fi and mobile carrier signals and battery strength here.

But I don't know if it's any trick to do that or something. Any ideas?

Comment: Just to help you in your search: the notification bar as you call it is generally called **statusbar**.

Comment: @miva2 Edited, thanks ^^

Comment: You're welcome :) In the question you linked, someone in the comments mentions there is an app who does this. Might be worth looking into. Eventually decompile it if you don't find more information or just straight up ask the developers. I'm having troubles with the status bar myself (transparent color).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - you cannot do this in stock releases of Android.

The right side has a set of preconfigured icons in a specific order. You cannot add to them, change them or remove them - they are controlled by the system.

The only way to add your own icon to the set of system icons is to build your own version of Android.

Besides, what's wrong with the left-hand side?!

Comment: Is there any version update of Android? I mean to can't add right icons on the notification bar.

Comment: Yes you can. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31231609/creating-a-button-in-android-toolbar

Comment: @Cade The question you reference is about a toolbar inside an App. This question is about the **statusbar** that's used to show notifications - it's completely different.