# add app icon to the right side of the status bar

Tags: android, android-icons, android-statusbar

is it possible to add my app icon to the right side of the status bar (along side the wifi icon, bluetooth icon, etc)?
My app start a service in the background so I want do show my app icon when the service is active.

Thank you

Alessandro

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973208/icon-in-the-status-bar-when-application-is-running

Answer (score 0):

You can show app icon on the right side of `ActionBar` (or `Toolbar`) using this:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
// or Toolbar toolbar = getSupportActionBar();

actionBar.setDisplayOptions(actionBar.getDisplayOptions()
        | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(actionBar.getThemedContext());
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_image);
ActionBar.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
        ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.RIGHT
                | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
actionBar.setCustomView(imageView);
```

For status bar, you will need to create your custom layout/override framework code, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20490810/4849804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26000002/4849804) answers.

Answer (score 0):

There are different API's for each. See below:

```
Notification.Builder nb = new Notification.Builder(context)
.setContentTitle("title")
.setContentText("content")
.setAutoCancel(true)
.setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.small_icon)
.setTicker(s.getText());
```

see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setSmallIcon%28int%29) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setLargeIcon%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29)

OR

As an alternative, you could use a custom notification layout.