# How to Show Status Bar Icons on the Right like Betternet?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

Before you flag this as duplicate, I researched this question a long time ago and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2540067/543711) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32210154/543711), which both suggest that the right side of the notification bar is a *system apps ONLY zone*.

However, I recently used [Betternet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.freevpnintouch&hl=en) and after connecting to the VPN, these two icons appear:

[image: Betternet app screenshot]

Betternet is not a system app, and my HTC On3 M8 is *not* rooted. **How did they do it?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The left icon is a `Notification`. These can be displayed by any app.

The right icon is a standard icon, added there by Android, indicating an active VPN connection. These are not put there by apps directly, though certain things that apps implement (e.g., `VpnService`) might result in an icon being shown there.

Comment: Oh. Never though the `key icon` is a stock icon. Thanks. There goes my dream of displaying my icon on the right :\

Comment: @iturki: Yeah, sorry, AFAIK there still no way for apps to put icons on the right, other than triggering stock ones (VPN, alarm clock, etc.). Custom ROMs, of course, can do what they want.